# Uncaught TypeError: "#ddAid".append is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this simple code which is suppose to get ajax data and populate the dropdown but its giving me error in console that append is not an function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#oid").blur(function() {
        $.getJSON("ajax.php?act=getAdmins", {
            oid: $(this).val()
        }, function(data, status) {
            if (status == "success") {
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    ('#ddAid').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', index));
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And my ajax data is like this:

```
{"286":"Lorem Ipsum","125":"Dolor Sit","321":"Amet Lorem"}
```

Can anyone help as to why this is happening ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: missing `$` before `('#ddAid')`

Answer (score 0):

You can append straight html without chaining all of those jQuery methods. Although you probably don't want to call `.append()` in a loop, that could be pretty resource heavy if you have alot of items to loop over. Instead you can build the html and then append it all at once.

Also, [$.getJson()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) has it's own methods for success and failure handling, using those will help with readability and removes unnecessary case checking.

```
$('#oid').blur(function() {
  $.getJSON('ajax.php?act=getAdmins', { oid: this.value })
    .done(function(data) {
      let options = '';
      //when looping an object, you get the key, not the index
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        options += `<option value="${key}">${value}</option>`; 
      });
      //you might want .html() or some sort of first blur check here
      //otherwise your select options will grow every time this handler is called
      $('#ddAid').append(options);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      //code to handle errors
    });
});
```

Or if you wanted to be even more efficient, but less readable, you could do it functionally:

```
.done(function(data) {
  $('#ddAid').append(Object.entries(data).map(entry => `<option value="${entry[0]}">${entry[1]}</option>`).join(''));
})
```

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) turns the object into an array

[.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) iterates over that array and turns it into html

[.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) collapses the array into a string

If you're not familiar with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), they're pretty great.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was confused because on one page my old code was working but on new it was not. But your code helped. Thanks again.